# Table border-collapse Issue

Tags: html, css, border

I have border-collapse: collapse set for a table. It looks fine except that the bottom border is cut-off.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you setting the border css property on each td?

Comment: @eulerfx, yes. This issue is resolved anyway, I just can't select my own answer.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted them and replaced them with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a white pixel and used it as a repeating background-image on right instead of a white border, issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the table's height to auto.

Comment: Table or row height? How'd that help anyway?

Comment: I had a similar problem which was fixed by setting the table height, just a suggestion.